# How to attach a TAB with an application to an existing channel?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How to attach a TAB with an application to an existing channel?
I'm creating Teams Groups + Channels and adding members to them.

But also I need to add some specific TABs foreach channel, specifically I need to add a TAB linked to a Sharepoint List.

The documentation states that using this API call you can Add an application to a team,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{app-id}/apps

//POST BODY
{
  "id" : "xxxx-xxxx-4559-a332-xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

But the applications are related to channels thru TABs, nor to teams itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible today via the Microsoft Graph, you can [upvote the uservoice entry](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31531228-provide-an-api-method-to-get-a-list-of-all-tabs-in) which hopefully will help the Microsoft Graph team prioritize it over other investments.

EDIT: Microsoft just release a new set of beta endpoints for teams yesterday, including a way to create new tabs see [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channels_tabs_add)

Comment: I don't know if you get a notification when an answer gets edited, but Microsoft just released new endpoints to allow to do this.

Comment: I solved using an alpha endpoint 2 weeks ago, I did'nt push that soution here because those endpoints are changing quite often. God to know that now are on beta at least.

Comment: I'm currently having an issue on the beta endpoint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556199/listing-microsoft-teams-tabs-always-returns-404 for the alpha one however I'm getting a segment not found for teams, what URI are you using?

Comment: isn't public  I got access for being working at ms engineering.