# listing Microsoft Teams tabs always returns 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've been trying this scenario on a couple of different tenants so far:

- use an existing team or create a new one through the UI
- add a tab (let's say OneNote) to a channel
- query the [list tabs endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channels_tabs_list) (through graph explorer)

I always get a 404 response. If I replace in my query `tabs` by `messages` I get the messages.

In terms of permissions I have the default graph explorer one + Group.Read.All.

Here is the latest request Id I got `2a180611-b637-4aa4-be27-9e42cbb27ab9` on tenant `dev2tolead12`. (`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/7471ee8d-0ed3-4f22-80ee-3b513e42e6ac/channels/19:9a0544b274654ef8ac97761ebd91b471@thread.skype/tabs`)

**My question: what am I missing for this request to work?**

Comment: It is like, clearly a bug. I'm receiving the same using the beta endpoint

Comment: Take a look, just reported. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35569321--list-tabs-in-channel-broken-in-beta-api

Comment: Hopefully they'll come across this post as well. I upvoted your "idea" thanks!

Comment: Interestingly it is working on the Microsoft tenant.

Comment: @JuanK I dug into the Graph logs for your request you reported in uservoice and it looks like the Graph gateway is failing to deserialize the response stream.  It also seems to take a very long time to fail.  Can you repro this issue consistently? Does it take a long time to fail?  Anything unusual about the names of your tabs, or the content in the tabs? The websiteUrl of the tab?

Comment: @DarrelMiller I'm using default tabs and channels. the request doesn't take long and I'm querying to list all tabs in the channel

Comment: @darrel_miller It only takes some time to execute but using some internal alpha Channel that i have used/tested few weeks ago.

Comment: Someone on the Teams PM team is investigating this. We will have some good news shortly, but for now, assume there is an issue with this that needs fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint started working in my tenants today. My guess is Microsoft fixed something recently

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, we thought we had deployed the tabs API to all tenants, but had actually deployed it to only some of them – this has been fixed.

Comment: If you are one of the contributors of the described software, please present yourself as so (with a little more info). Then, maybe this can become a proper answer.